# Optional.ifPresent (what if not)

Tags: java

I'm trying to build a flow based on options returned by methods.

My question is: Is there a way to build a flow that splits in case of getting for example `Optional<int> (some)` and executing another flow in the other case in a nice way? (not of using if else switch ternary )

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Do you mean [java.util.Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) (instead of Option)?

Comment: Remember that the improvements in Java 8 weren't meant to *replace* the saner ways to do things before, but add to them. Going out of your way to replace a simple `if` (or `for` etc.) with a more complicated way, just to use streams/optionals/etc. is just a bad idea. Just because we got some functional fun doesn't make Java a very good functional language.

Comment: i gave an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is orElseGet:

The following returns 6:

```
Optional.of(5).map(value -> value + 1)
              .orElseGet(() -> 1);
```

And this will return 1:

```
Optional.<Integer>empty().map(value -> value + 1)
                         .orElseGet(() -> 1)
```

orElseGet is takes a supplier, so you can execute arbitrary code in there so long as you return a value.

Comment: This is not the answer. OP is asking about executing an arbitrary code when optional has non-null value and different arbitrary code when it has null.

In your case, while you can add an arbitrary code there, you are forced to return some value that OP does not care about. What should this value be? It can be anything really.